# How I can hide and show tabs conditionally in Ionics?

Tags: tabs, ionic-framework

The case is the following: I have a `ion-tabs` container with several `ion-tab` elements, and different users that logs into my application. What I need to do is to show or hide the `ion-tab` elements depending on the user type logged.

I have tried to hide just one tab to check if it is possible and the only thing that have worked is:

```
<ion-tab title="..." icon="..." ui-sref="..." class="ng-hide">
```

The problem is that I need to do this dynamically, and if I use a directive like `ng-show="false"` or my own directive to add `class="ng-hide"`, it does not work. Not even encapsulating the `ion-tab` inside a `div`and hide this `div`.

What am I doing wrong? Can somebody help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you are already using class attribute on ion-tab, you can modify it as follows?...

```
<ion-tab title="..." icon="..." ui-sref="..." class="class1 class2 {{myFunctionName()}}">
```

> And in your controller...

```
$scope.myFunctionName = function(){
    if () {
    // return "ng-show";
    } else {
    // return "ng-hide";
    }
}
```

Comment: Glad it Helped :). !! (Y)

Answer (score 5):

Very late to the party here but encountered this problem and found a more elegant solution (imho).

Using ng-show doesn't work on ion-tab (not sure why not) so instead use ng-if to call a function:

```
<ion-tab ng-if="showElement()">
```

Then in your controller:

```
$scope.showElement = function() {
    //logic to return a bool
}
```

I think this is more elegant because it means the element is never rendered rather than rendered and hidden.

Comment: Problem with this is the other tabs render first, thus this tab is always last (far right) in the tab bar.

Comment: same here, trying to see how to keep tab in place as it renders last when using ng-if

Answer (score 5):

There is no need to add class to hide and show ion-tab.
We need to just maintain one condition for "hidden" attribute of ion-tab like following-

```
 <ion-tabs class="tabs-icon-top tabs-color-active-positive "> 
    <ion-tab hidden="{{condition}}" title="Home" icon-off="ion-ios-home- outline" icon-on="ion-ios-home" href="#/tab/chats"></ion-tab>
    <ion-tab hidden="{{condition}}" title="Log-in" icon-off="ion-person-stalker" icon-on="ion-person-stalker" href="#/tab/login">
</ion-tab>
```

Using this we can show/hide tab.

Comment: Glad to know it helped !

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using ng-show to call a function?

```
<ion-tab title="..." icon="..." ui-sref="..." ng-show="myFunctionName()">
```

And in your controller...

```
$scope.myFunctionName = function(){
    //return true or false here
}
```

Comment: I have tried and it doesn't work. The problem seems to appear when I put a directive inside `ion-tab`, because if I use `class="ng-hide"`, it works, but if I use `ng-class="..."`, it doesn't work. So I cannot use neither `ng-show` nor `ng-hide`.